# How to get the "Encrypt external SD card" option to show (on a LG Optimus F6)?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, encryption, disk-encryption

The "Encrypt external SD card" option doesn't show up under `Settings -> Security` on my LG Optimus F6, or my Huawei Y301-A2.

A microSD card, FAT32 formatted and empty, is inserted and recognized correctly. The "encrypt device" option shows up, but the "Encrypt external SD card" does not.

How do I get this option to show up? This is using Android 4.1.2

Comment: Solution should ideally not involve having to use a custom ROM.

Comment: Your ROM doesn't support it http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26425/does-androids-full-filesystem-encryption-also-encrypt-the-sdcard

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those exact models, but on Jelly Bean in general, you must enable a password on your phone to encrypt external SD.

Security  -> Set up screen lock -> Password.

Then you'll need to set a password for the SD.

Step-by-step tutorial with images:
http://visihow.com/Encrypt_Files_on_Your_SD_Card_Using_Your_Android_Phone

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for the external SD.